# MPTT Django how to get children with user_id = some_user_id. NOT ALL children

Tags: django, mptt

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:  # for swagger generation only
        return CannedAnswer.objects.none()

    if self.action in ['list']:
        return CannedAnswer.objects.filter(
            Q(agent=self.request.user) | Q(agent__isnull=True) | Q(group__in=self.request.user.groups.all())).get_cached_trees()
    else:
        return CannedAnswer.objects.filter(agent=self.request.user)
```

This code returns me all children, but I want to get children who have agent = self.request.user

Comment: I see on line 7, you're OR'ing together several groups. Should some of those ORs be ANDs?

Comment: @NickODell It does not depend on